# Unable to run bootable drive

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb, flash, drive

It won't let me boot up ubuntu on the bootable drives. It just boots from my hdd everytime I select to run from the usb drive.

Answer (score 0):

If your BIOS fails to find a bootable drive, typically it will revert to the original boot configuration.

Which boot option are you selecting when selecting your boot device?  USB has three different labels in most BIOS I have used, and you have to use USB-HDD label when selecting a bootable usb.

If that doesn't work, try rearranging the boot priority of devices in your BIOS. Add as many devices as possible to the list of bootable devices; and put the HDD with OS installed on it at the bottom of the boot order.  Then when you restart, it will automatically boot from anything other than the HDD if possible.  But you gotta remember to change it back later!

Comment: I used a 4 gig flash drive I had and it then booted from my laptop where it asked if I wanted to install to my hdd (which I didn't) so   I also plugged in the 64 gb flash drive I originally intended to use to try to install it only to get a "no root directory found"  error 
either way neither boot up ubuntu on my desktop for some reason.

Comment: You've tried following this guide?

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: Correct. I've done it with unetbootin as well.

Comment: Which motherboard are you using?  And to confirm, is this a standard USB drive?  How much storage does it have and is it usb 2.0?  Thanks

Comment: the 4gb usb 2.0 works
the 64gb usb 3.0 doesn't. 
my desktop mobo is GIGABYTE GA-970A-UD3 AM3+ AMD 970 SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 ATX AMD Motherboard

Comment: Try updating your bios with Gigabyte.  http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3907#  And review the compatibilities of your motherboard.  Not all BIOS are compatible with USB 3.0 drives.  You might have to get another USB drive, sorry.

Comment: Yeah, I ordered a replacement usb drive so that should help.

Comment: Good luck, let me know how it works.